# how do I add vertical lines for indented blocks in algorithmic latex package?

Tags: algorithm, latex, line

I am using the algorithmic package in latex.
I would like to include the vertical lines for indented blocks as the picture below.

What is the command for this. Cannot see it in the documentation. Is it possible?

[image: example image]

Here is the code:

```
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{This is an algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}
\REQUIRE 
\REPEAT 
\FORALL{xyz $\in$ zyx}
\STATE1) {some statement}
\STATE2) {some additional statement}
\STATE {some other statement}
\UNTIL{solution is found}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

Comment: Please make a [mre]

Comment: I have added the example code. Thank you

Comment: That's not compilable. No documentclass, no document environment ...

Comment: And even after guessing such stuff, it does not compile :(

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `algorithm2e` package to get vertical lines:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{This is an algorithm}
\Repeat{solution is found}{
  \ForAll{xyz $\in$ zyx}{
    1) some statement
  
    2) some additional statement
  }
  some other statement
}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is the right document class I am using. Thanks for this. Looks like what I was after, one last thing. Could you reproduce in your code also the end for statement?

Comment: If you want to add an explicit end, try `\usepackage[ruled,lined]{algorithm2e}`

Comment: Thanks. I added this  `\SetAlgoLined\SetArgSty{}` it did the job !